# Practical implications of using bsd licensed code

Tags: licensing, bsd

Up to now, I've mainly been programming for fun projects on a small scale. Now I am planning the release of a larger iOS application in which I use BSD licensed code. I've know this is one of the simplest licenses and should be easy to implement, but the restrictions still leave me puzzled on how I should implement them.

As far as I understand, I need to include a copyright message and the restrictions in the application. How do I do this practically?

Is it sufficient to add a comment in one of the information menus saying "copyright author XXX" and repeat the restrictions, or should I implement this differently?

I know this probably is a stupid question, but licensing is new to me and I have trouble finding references on how I can implement it (or examples). I hope someone is able to help me!

Comment: There are no stupid questions when asked the right way as you you did here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You typically add credits in the "About" section in the menu.

Here is how Spotify do it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: More canonically, you add the note about the BSD license terms in the same places you display the copyright and/or license terms for the program itself (eg. About dialog, license page of the help screens, splash screen). It also has to appear in the printed or electronic documentation if any, usually on the same page as the rest of the program's copyright and license terms.